# How to get end of spinning event with wxPython

Tags: python, events, wxpython, spinner, wxwidgets

I have a SpinCtrl on my window and want to process a spin event only on mouse up or arrow key up (end of spinning). Because there is no event like this, I wanted to use a mouse event. But if I bind `EVT_LEFT_DOWN` and `EVT_LEFT_UP`, `EVT_SPIN` is not sent anymore and the control does nothing.

How can I perceive an end of spinning event with a SpinCtrl? Is it possible to call the default event handler on `EVT_LEFT_DOWN` and the other events?

Comment: You can call the underlying event handlers by calling `event.Skip()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Who's interested: I got a solution:

```
class SpinEndEventManager(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._controls = []
        self._event_handlers = []
        self._has_spinned = False

    def add(self, control, event_handler):
        self._controls.append(control)
        self._event_handlers.append(event_handler)
        control.Bind(wx.EVT_SPINCTRL, self._on_event)
        control.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_UP, self._on_event)
        control.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN, self._on_event)
        control.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_UP, self._on_event)

    def _on_event(self, event):
        is_spin_end_event = False
        event_type = event.GetEventType()
        control = event.GetEventObject()
        if event_type == wx.wxEVT_COMMAND_SPINCTRL_UPDATED:
            self._has_spinned = True
        elif event_type == wx.wxEVT_LEFT_UP:
            if self._has_spinned:
                is_spin_end_event = True
            event.Skip()
        elif event_type == wx.wxEVT_KEY_DOWN:
            key = event.GetKeyCode()
            old_value = control.GetValue()
            if key == wx.WXK_UP:
                value = old_value + 1
            elif key == wx.WXK_DOWN:
                value = old_value - 1
            control.SetValue(value)
            value = control.GetValue()
            if value != old_value:
                self._has_spinned = True
            if key == wx.WXK_DOWN:
                value_string_length = len(str(value))
                control.SetSelection(value_length, value_string_length)
        elif event_type == wx.wxEVT_KEY_UP:
            if self._has_spinned:
                is_spin_end_event = True
        if is_spin_end_event:
            self._has_spinned = False
            index = self._controls.index(control)
            self._event_handlers[index](event)
```